# Use shell redirection to pre-enter text into an interactive command?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Just to say it up front: I am aware that most programs that have an interactive prompt also have some kind of initialization file or the ability to set a command flag that will run something, and *then* drop you into the interactive prompt.  However, I'm interested in the solution at the shell level.

---

Let's say I have a command `xyz` that I run from a shell, and it takes over my terminal and gives me an interactive prompt where I can run newline terminated commands.

Let's say I have two commands (two lines) I want to run at the beginning of my interactive session, each and every time I run `xyz`.

If these two lines were the *only* commands I wanted to run, of course I could just run:

```
printf '%s\n' 'first command' 'second command' | xyz
```

Or alternatively, if I had a whole bunch of commands to run but I know all of them in advance, I could just put them all in a file and run:

```
xyz < commands-file.txt
```

However, if **I want to get a standard interactive prompt, with the exact same result as if I typed `xyz` and then manually typed in my `first command` and `second command`**...is there a way to do this in the shell (e.g. in a shell function) using redirection?

---

The obvious apparent solutions such as `sed -e '1ifirst command' -e '1isecond command' | xyz` don't work, either because `xyz` can detect that the input is not coming from a terminal or because the `sed` output is buffered; not sure which.

Comment: take a look at `qodem`

Comment: http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @IporSircer, no, I know about `expect`.  That isn't relevant.  I've bolded the applicable line to make it more obvious.

Comment: @Serge, I hadn't heard of `qodem` but a quick search and browse of several of the results doesn't reveal the relevance to my question.  Care to clarify?

Comment: You want to feed something into an `xyz` programs `stdin` prior you type something else manually. The simple shell redirection would not help much (even `cat file - | xyz` would not help as xyz would detect that stdin is not a tty and cat does buffering) . You need some terminal emulation program that 1) is capable to initially send something to the sub-process and 2) is not buffering the input and 3) looks as a tty to the subprocess

Comment: You presumably don't want to use [TIOCSTI](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) either, to stuff data into the terminal as if typed?