# How to send standard input through a pipe

Tags: command-line, pipe, io-redirection

I need to send a standard input or a keycode right after the program starts.

For example

```
$ program | F3
```

Comment: Which is it, if you need to send key strokes you'll probably need something like `expect`, if you want the program to read from `stdin` you can put it on the other side, pipes go left to right, so `stdout` on the left gets connected to `stdin` on the right, e.g., `echo Input | program` will send the string `input` to `stdin` of `program`

Comment: Related (but not answered) question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/311049/135943

Answer (score 6):

You'd need to define *starts* there.

You can insert the sequences of characters sent by your terminal when you press `F3` into the terminal device input buffer *before* running your program with the TIOCSTI ioctl() on some systems like Linux:

```
{
   perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph";
   ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "","@ARGV"' "$(tput kf3)"
   program
}
```

Or you can use something like `expect` to run your program in a faked terminal layer, wait for it to output some prompt (or any indication that it is *started* up to the point you expect it to), and send that output then:

```
expect -c 'spawn -noecho program; expect {>} {send [exec tput kf3]}; interact'
```

(here expecting a `>` prompt, replace by some string that `program` outputs when it's ready to read input).

You can also replace its stdin with a pipe, but if that application expects things like <kbd>F3</kbd> key presses, it's most likely an interactive application so will probably not like it when it's stdin is not a terminal. You can always give it a try anyway:

```
tput kf3 | program
```

However then, after `program` has read the output of `tput`, it will see end-of-file (nothing more to  be read), which it may cause it to exit. With:

```
{ tput kf3; cat; } | program
```

We send the output of `kf3` and then use `cat` to forward everything you type on the terminal to `program`. Then again, it's unlikely to work as most probably `program` would put the terminal in a mode where the input is sent as soon as you type and disable the `echo` which it can no longer do as its input is not the terminal.

You could and do that same setting yourself:

```
saved_settings=$(stty -g)
stty -icanon -echo min 1 time 0
{ tput kf3; cat; } | program
stty "$saved_settings"
```